# Приложение падает со StackOverflow, чем посмотреть содержимое стека во время падения?

Tags: java, стек

приложение падает при попытке сериализации. Есть ли какие-то инструменты или способы, чтобы посмотреть объекты какого типа заняли весь стек, чтобы проще было выявить циклические зависимости(они хоть и разруливаются jvm,

Comment: Варианты: 1. Посмотреть стек 2. Логировать весь код и найти место, где началась рекурсия. 3. Комментировать построчно, пока проблемный код не будет найден. И после этого можно в этот вопрос добавить тот проблемный код :)

Comment: Скорее всего у вас закольцованные ссылки (circular references) в дереве объектов, которое вы пытаетесь сериализовать.

Comment: Так, я думаю тут надо указать какой механизм используется для сериализации.

Comment: 99.9 % что да, циклические сылки. Дело все в том, что java умеет их разруливать, но съедает стек вызовов при этом. Поскольку листов достаточно много различных, мне бы хотелось узнать, какой именно из них ломает сериализацию, чтобы потом сесть и отдельной задачей выпилить эти циклические зависимости

Answer (score 1):

Перехватите [`java.lang.StackOverflowError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html) (внимание, это наследник Error а не Exception!) и вызовите ему [`printStackTrace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace()).

Comment: я увижу пачку повторяющихся вызовов, а как посмотреть листы с какими объектами переполнили стек во время падения?

Comment: @VladislavOsipenkov отладчик + точки останова вам помогут.